# Date and String handling in Ignite SQL queries

Tags: ignite

I am about to try Ignite to compare it to Hazelcast performance-wise as data grid. As I am researching all of the features I need, there is no mention of date (java.util.Date) and String comparison in SQL queries (less than, greater, etc.) I am guessing it relies on Comparable (I would), but would like to know the exact answer.

Another related question (probably better asked separately) is about indexes. Hazelcast has indexes and the so-called Portable serialization format which essentially stores a subset of fields separately from the serialized object to avoid deserialization. How can I guarantee to avoid it in Ignite SQL queries? All fields indexed? What about compound indexes, etc. I am wondering how complex queries work internally, as there are no compound indexes according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date and String actually are considered as SQL types TIMESTAMP and VARCHAR respectively, so it is not about Comparable. But for any non-standard types Ignite SQL will rely on Comparable if they participate in indexes or queries.

According to docs compound indexes are supported and called [Group indexes](https://ignite.incubator.apache.org/releases/1.2.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/annotations/QuerySqlField.Group.html). And complex queries work pretty well :)

Currently Ignite does not store indexed values separately but instead keeps deserialized Java object and uses reflection to access properties. In near future (hopefully in weeks) Ignite is going to release a feature allowing to index serialized objects and access fields without keeping Java objects (or even having indexed Java classes on nodes).

Comment: Thanks. Cache scan especially with reflection doesn't sound too encouraging, but hopefully there is some magic, that'd beat Hazelcast, which queries are, believe you or not, slower that on-disk databases e.g. Mongo. My single-node benchmark is 100K of appr. 1K records filtered and ordered by one indexed field (with all recommended optimizations in place).

Comment: Ignite SQL does not use cache scan if you have correct indexes. Also reflection in recent java works quite fast, so nothing to worry about.

Comment: There is indeed no scan, because it requires "query field" metadata for every field used in the SQL query - which works very similar to Hazelcast's Portable, except much faster (at the cost of memory, but who cares about memory). I have finished incorporating Ignite into Px100 Data (you can check it out on Github - https://github.com/a-rog/px100data) and it works very well. The benchmark is coming up.